# Scala: how to flatten an Array of a tuple of tuples?

Tags: arrays, scala, tuples

I'm trying to flatten the following structure at scala:

```
Array[((String, String, String),(String, String, String))]
```

To obtain:

```
(String, String, String, String, String, String)
```

So far, I tried something similar to:

```
val  = payload.map(_.productIterator.toList.map(_.toString)).toList
```

which produces: `List[List[String]]`

Any ideas about how to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Combining tuples can be done manually (`map { case ((a,b,c), (d,e,f)) => (a,b,c,d,e,f) }`) but how would you like to combine each such tuple into a single value? Concatenate values on corresponding positions?

Answer (score 3):

Tuples aren't something which can be easily flattened - Scala 3 offers the way to concatenate them:

```scala
val xs: Array[((String, String, String),(String, String, String))]

xs.map { case (t1, t2) =>
  t1 ++ t2
} // Array[(String, String, String, String, String, String)]
```

but in Scala 2 you'd have to combine them manually

```scala
val xs: Array[((String, String, String),(String, String, String))]

xs.map { case ((a, b, c), (d, e, f)) =>
  (a, b, c, d, e, f)
} // Array[(String, String, String, String, String, String)]
```

Once you have array of tuples... you still cannot "just" flatten it because what would be intuitive, build-in, default way of combining all tuples in array into one tuple? You can do it, e.g. with foldLeft/foldRight/reduce but you still have to tell HOW:

```scala
val xs2: Array[(String, String, String, String, String, String)]

xs2.foldLeft(initialValue) { (tuple1, tuple) =>
  // your definition how to combine them
}
```

e.g. if you wanted to concatenate values on corresponding positions

```scala
val xs: Array[((String, String, String),(String, String, String))]

xs.map { case ((a, b, c), (d, e, f)) =>
  (a, b, c, d, e, f)
}.foldLeft(("", "", "", "", "", "")) {
  case ((a1,b1,c1,d1,e1,f1), (a2,b2,c2,d2,e2,f2)) =>
    (a1+a2, b1+b2, c1+c2, d1+d2, e1+e2, f1+f2)
} // (String, String, String, String, String, String)
```

It could also be done in 1 step with:

```scala
val xs: Array[((String, String, String),(String, String, String))]

xs.foldLeft(("", "", "", "", "", "")) {
  case ((a1,b1,c1,d1,e1,f1), ((a2,b2,c2),(d2,e2,f2))) =>
    (a1+a2, b1+b2, c1+c2, d1+d2, e1+e2, f1+f2)
} // (String, String, String, String, String, String)
```

But the exact implementation depends on what you understand by "flattening" array of tuples of tuples into a tuple.

Answer (score 0):

you can use productIterator but since it returns Any you need to match on the types you have:

```
val x=Seq((("A","B","C"),("D","E","F")),(("A1","B1","C1"),("D1","E1","F1")))
x.flatMap(_.productIterator
    .flatMap{
        case ys:(String, String, String)=>
          ys.productIterator.map{ 
               case xs:String => xs 
  }})

res0: Seq[String] = List(A, B, C, D, E, F, A1, B1, C1, D1, E1, F1)
```